# Is it possible to inject shell/python commands from a configuration file?

Tags: python, security

Say you have a some meta data for a custom file format that your python app reads. Something like a csv with variables that can change as the file is manipulated:

```
var1,data1
var2,data2
var3,data3
```

So if the user can manipulate this meta data, do you have to worry about someone crafting a malformed meta data file that will allow some arbitrary code execution? The only thing I can imagine if you you made the poor choice to make `var1` be a shell command that you execute with `os.sys(data1)` in your own code somewhere. Also, if this were C then you would have to worry about buffers being blown, but I don't think you have to worry about that with python. If your reading in that data as a string is it possible to somehow escape the string `"\n os.sys('rm -r /')`, this SQL like example totally wont work, but is there similar that is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing what you say there (plain text, just reading and parsing a simple format), you will be safe. As you indicate, Python is generally safe from the more mundane memory corruption errors that C developers can create if they are not careful. The SQL injection scenario you note is not a concern when simply reading in files in python.

**However**, if you are concerned about security, which it seems you are (interjection: good for you! A good programmer should be lazy *and* paranoid), here are some things to consider:

*Validate all input*. Make sure that each piece of data you read is of the expected size, type, range, etc. Error early, and don't propagate tainted variables elsewhere in your code.

- Do you know the expected names of the vars, or at least their format? Make sure the validate that it is the kind of thing you expect before you use it. If it should be just letters, confirm that with a regex or similar.
- Do you know the expected range or format of the data? If you're expecting a number, make sure it's a number before you use it. If it's supposed to be a short string, verify the length; you get the idea.
- What if you get characters or bytes you don't expect? What if someone throws unicode at you?
- If any of these are paths, make sure you canonicalize and know that the path points to an acceptable location before you read or write.

Some specific things **not** to do:

- os.system(attackerControlledString)
- eval(attackerControlledString)
- `__import__(attackerControlledString)`
- pickle/unpickle attacker controlled content ([here's why](http://nadiana.com/python-pickle-insecure))

Also, rather than rolling your own config file format, consider [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) or something like [JSON](http://www.json.org/). A well understood format (and libraries) helps you get a leg up on proper validation.

OWASP would be my normal go-to for providing a "further reading" link, but their Input Validation page needs help. In lieu, this looks like a reasonably pragmatic read: "[Secure Programmer: Validating Input](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-sp2.html)". A slightly dated but more python specific one is "[Dealing with User Input in Python](http://tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/83/evans.html)"

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful information, I was actually considering using pickle... that would have been unfortunate.

Comment: Chris; anything else you were hoping for to make this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Depends entirely on the way the file is processed, but generally this should be safe. In Python, you have to put in some effort if you want to treat text as code and execute it.